# rails migration doesn't work with an empty down function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I generated a rails 3.2 migration with an empty down function, because the migration is irreversible (and I don't want to throw an exception). I run the migration successfully, but it has no effect. When I rollback, and run db:migrate again, the effects does apply.

I solved this easily by filling the empty down function with a code which does nothing, but it's still pretty ugly.

Does anyone knows why this happens? Is this a rails bug?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev true, but even though some people googling for question and landing here, deserve an answer ;)

Comment: thanks, I wasn't even aware stackoverflow had an accept feature until a few weeks ago :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception is throwed to prevent destroying your database, if its irreversable, then that's probably the right thing to do.
Your `#down` could look like this:

```
  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration, "Explain why its irreversable!"
  end
```

That will save others a lot of headache as it clearly notifies about irreversable migration and explains the reason behind it :)

**EDIT:** I cannot confirm this behaviour for Rails 3.2.3. I've created several different migrations without `#down`, and no exceptino was raised. Maybe it's something in your code, which you didn't show a bit.

**EDIT 2:** Just to recap, when you're using up/down method, its your responsibility to raise `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration`. In other case, nothing will happen (`#down` defined in AR will just return nil). The behaviour is different when you use `#change`. In some cases the mentioned exception can be raised by `#inverse` defined here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/565bfb9cd49285ebaa170141b4996c22ba81de43/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb#L39 which is expected behaviour.

Comment: this is probably the right solution, yet it doesn't answer the behavior i described :)